# array usando explode

Tags: php

tengo que generar un array con esta sintaxis `array( 100 => [ 68, 69, 72 ], 103 => [ 68, 69, 72 ], 205 => [ 68, 69, 70, 71, 72 ], 343 => [ 68, 69, 72, 73 ] )`

El primer campo equivale a tallas y el segundo a los colores asignados a esas tallas.Los datos los tengo almacenados en mysql por un valor separado por comas con lo que hago un explode para separarlos y generar un array.

los campos a consultar serian tallas que es un varchar y colores que es otro varchar y ambos almacenan números separados por coma 100,101,135,120

la consulta la estoy haciendo asi:

```
    $consulta = "select * from `Articulos` where `id`= 111 ";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($Conectar, $consulta);
    $datos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
$taLlas = explode(",", $datos['talla']);
```

No tengo muy claro cual seria la sintaxis para generarlo.

Muchas gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Si los campos vienen de SQL, la API o la clase que uses para consultar las tablas (PDO, mysqli...) tiene métodos para devolverte los resultados en forma de array... no tienes por qué reconvertirlos de nuevo. No obstante a tu pregunta le faltan datos y para poder darte una respuesta certera, óptima y adecuada.

Comment: uso mysqli ¿puedo generar un array de ese estilo directamente?

Comment: Puedes generar ese y cualquier array en la forma que sea. Eso depende de cómo están guardados tus datos y de la forma en que los consultas. Sin detalles de la estructura de tus tablas, de lo que has intentando y del resultado final que quieres... es difícil darte una respuesta. Si no sabes por dónde empezar, entonces quizá deberías investigar (aquí mismo hay muy buenas respuestas), sobre la forma de consultar y leer datos usando `mysqli`. Un buen punto de partida es el Manual de PHP que tiene información es castellano.

Comment: he puesto el poco código que tengo del tema.

Answer (score 1):

Si tu columna se llama `tallas` y como dices en ella tienes valores separados por coma. Supongamos que quieres crear un array.

```
$consulta = "select * from `Articulos` where `id`= 111 ";
$resultado = mysqli_query($Conectar, $consulta);
$datos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);


while($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
{
    $arrTallas[] = array($datos["id"]=>explode(",",$datos["tallas"]));
}

print_r($arrTallas);
```

Se creará un array como este, ya que aquí: **`$arrTallas[] = array($datos["id"]=>explode(",",$datos["tallas"]));`** lo que se hizo fue crear un array asociativo en el cual contiene un registro por cada array cuya clave sería el valor de la columna `id` (suponiendo que sea eso lo que quieres y que en tu tabla hay una columna que se llame así) y dentro de cada `id` varios arrays a su vez obtenidos con explode sobre la fila `tallas` usando la coma `,` como separador.

La lectura de ese array se haría entonces mediante un bucle cualquiera de PHP.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [100] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 68
                    [1] => 69
                    [2] => 72

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [205] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 68
                    [1] => 69
                    [2] => 70
                    [3] => 71
                    [4] => 72
               )

        )

)
```

Comment: Realmente lo que necesito es que de cada talla me ponga todos los colores, ósea donde has puesto el id tendría que ir la talla que esta en otro valor separado por coma. Pero con esto puedo intentar buscar la forma de hacerlo :) mil gracias.

Comment: @Killpe en teoría sería cuestión de hacer algo como esto: `$arrColores[] = array($datos["tallas"]=>explode(",",$datos["colores"]));`. Digo *en teoría* porque si `tallas`  es una array entonces harían quizá falta más niveles para recorrer cada clave de tallas y sus respectivos colores... o más bien diseñar la base de datos de otra manera o hacer la consulta de otra manera.